# ChromeDriver touch events always disabled

Tags: webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to lauch Chrome browser with touch events enabled, however when it always stats with touch events disabled (touch events doesn't work and "Emulate touch events" checkbox is not checked in "Dev. tools" -> Settings -> Overrides)
My code is:

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.addArguments("touch-events"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
```

Is there any way to launch Chrome with Touch Events enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing two settings.  First there's whether or not the browser supports the touch event APIs.  That's controlled by the -touch-events flag (enabled, disabled or automatic which means enabled if a touch screen is detected).  When it is true, you'll see, for example ('ontouchstart' in window) is true (and many other properties/function exists).

Secondly there is a devtools feature which generates synthetic touch events from mouse input.  This technically works regardless of whether the touchy APIs are enabled (but some sites may legitimately be confused if some touch APIs don't exist, yet they receive touch events).  As far as I know, there is no way to enable the developer tools and turn on a feature from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

`opt.addArguments("--touch-events=disabled");`

Comment: doesn't work on Chrome 88, even if you put opt.addArguments("--touch-events=enabled");